# i can't get my mp3 file size in php na dmysql

Tags: php, mysql

i try to print my mp3 file size., but it's give me error.
i print file name and file path completely.
but i can't print file size..

my mp3 file name =[Songs.pk]Tanu weds manu-03-piya.mp3
and this mp3 file is in " tanu weds manu" folder

this is my code..

```html
$conn = ("localhost","root","","test1");

$sql = " SELECT `song_name`,`song_path` FROM `table1` WHERE `id`=75";

$query = mysqli_query($conn , $sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){


  $name_of_file =$row["song_name"];
  $file_path = $row["song_path"];
  $file_size = filesize($row["song_path"]);

  echo $name_of_file."<br>";
  echo $file_path."<br>";
  echo $file_size."<br>";  
}
```

i got this error.

warning: filesize(): state for tanu wends manu/.../ on line 16

Comment: does the file actually exist?

Comment: where is this " tanu weds manu"  located???

Comment: in wamp server "www/tanu weds manu"

Answer (score 0):

copy the file location that you have printed .. check if the file really exists, it can be either path is wrong or file is missing .